# Custom ListView with button

Tags: android

I using custom adapter for displaying a list of items in my project,
Right now it is working fine.but now i got another requirement that i need to put a button on each item.
If put the button like that then the `onItemClickListenter()` for that item is not working ,instead `onClickListener()` for that button is working.

But according to my context both `onClickListenter()` for button and `onItemClickListener()` for that item should work.Can somebody please help me if know the technique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to set up your listeners?

Comment: post your custom adapter and list item xml....

Comment: Please post your code ... both would work if implemented properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than putting buttons on row use image views as many required and set on click listener to them, Since imageViews are not focusable

Answer (score 2):

As `Button` is a `focusable` view thats why `onItemClick` isn't work. In *ur_row.xml* (where you placed that `Button`) add these attributes inside `Button` tag

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Inside your ***CustomAdapter's getView(...)*** set `onClickListener` for that `Button` this will fire both `onItemClick` for *ListView* and `onClick` for *Button*.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom adapter:

This project contains 4 parts:

1.**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);

    init();
}

/**
 * Init Data
 */
public void init(){
    List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        listItems.add("Test" + i);
    }
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.row_item,listItems);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
}
```

2.**MainActivity layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".main_activity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

3.**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context context;
private TextView itemListText;
private Button itemButton;
private List<String> listValues;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> listValues) {
    super(context, resource,listValues);
    this.context = context;
    this.listValues = listValues;
}

/**
 * getView method is called for each item of ListView
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String currentValue = listValues.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

    itemListText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemListText);
    itemListText.setText(currentValue);

    itemListText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Text Working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    itemButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemButton);
    //To lazy to implement interface
    itemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Button Working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

4.**Row Item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemListText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Select Text"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/itemButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Push me"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

TextView touch action

[image]

Button touch action

[image]

Comment: Please note that with your solution there will be no visual feedback after pressing list item. You would have to implement it for text and if there is more item elements then it's getting more complicated. Solution from @kaushik is simpler and keep item visual effects.

Comment: @Loop TextView has the same size as the list row, and on touch it will work, first image the toast is showing this.

Comment: @Monolescu Sebsastian I know it's working but it's not good solution for everyone. You cannot expect that everyone use `TextView` resized to the row height. Moreover `TextView` does not provide by default visual feedback as list item background does(dynamically change the background when item is pressed)